# The outcome for this news ticker by querying SharePoint list items using jQuery not come out

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery

I tried this code and paste to the content editor in sharepoint but then nothing came out. Just a blank space. I tried to inspect the marquee is working working but it just not showing the item it suppose to show. Please help.

```
    <script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {   

    var soapEnv ="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
                <soapenv:Body> \
                     <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                        <listName>News</listName> \
                        <viewFields> \
                            <ViewFields> \
                               <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
                           </ViewFields> \
                        </viewFields> \
                    </GetListItems> \
                </soapenv:Body> \
            </soapenv:Envelope>"; 

        $.ajax({
            url: "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapEnv,
            complete: Result,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
        });
    }); 

    function Result(xData, status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
            var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
            $("# news ").append(liHtml);
        });
    }  
</script>               

<marquee onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
                <ul id="news">  </ul>
</marquee>

<style>
         UL#news {
                     WIDTH: 620px;
                      OVERFLOW: hidden
         }

          UL#news LI {        
                       WIDTH: 600px;    
                       DISPLAY: inline;
                       HEIGHT: 99px;
        }
</style>
```

I already check the list name and field ref but still it didnt give any outcome. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the reason you are using SOAP and not REST? And what is the reason you are using a jQuery version from july 2013?

Comment: Im just trying my luck, Im still new with this, so I just try anything that was working for as long as I can see it working and learn from this. Why? Could you guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is an extra space in jquery selector

`$("# news ").append(liHtml);`

 Update it to: 
`$("#news").append(liHtml);`

Comment: thank you for your response.. i tried but still no outcome, still not calling my custom list item.

Comment: Any errors in browser developer dashboard console?

Comment: okay, i see lot of red section mentioning about the http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js

Comment: Could you please share the log

Comment: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: include.preload.js:465 Calling Element.createShadowRoot() for an element which already hosts a shadow root is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4668884095336448 for more details.

Comment: Try updating jquery link to https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js

Comment: still no luck.. :(

jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).ticker is not a function TypeError: $(...).ticker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://uni.u.com.my/Style%20Library/js/site.js:3:16)
    at j (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:29948)
    at k (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:30262) undefined
r.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2